# Why doen't the smallest number from user input gets added to the list?

Tags: c#, console-application

There was a test in school where we had to write a C# console program that reads positive integers below 100 from user input and then writes out some details like the biggest number. I used a list to store the numbers. I tested it with some random numbers I typed in but the program only adds the numbers to list starting with the second smallest one.

```
int count = 0;
List<int> bekertek = new List<int>();
int bekert = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
double atlag;
while (bekert > 0 && bekert < 100)
{
    bekert = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    count++;
    bekertek.Add(bekert);
}
/* This section is only for checking the list's elements
foreach (var i in bekertek)
    {
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}*/
Console.WriteLine("A bevitt adatok száma: {0}", count);
bekertek.Sort();
bekertek.Remove(bekertek.Last());
atlag = bekertek.Average();
Console.WriteLine("A legnagyobb érték: {0}", bekertek.Last());
Console.WriteLine("A legkisebb érték: {0}", bekertek.First());
Console.WriteLine("Az adatok átlaga: {0}", atlag);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `I tested it with some random numbers I typed in but the program only adds the numbers to list starting with the second smallest one`. And also something a bit off topic: the code is very hard to read as its combining English and Hungarian(? not 100% sure :)), I am not a native English speaker myself but I code in English as the frameworks etc. are in English too. Its just some advice, not relevant otherwise

Comment: I update my answer with a do...while loop.

Comment: I may have found the solution. Instead of adding a non-zero value to the bekert variable, I prompted the user for a number. But that number is not added to the list because it happened before the while loop. This is just a theory yet since I can't test it without a computer (I don't use my smartphone for testing and running programs on it). I'll test it when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For input in console, I think the do...while loop is the ideal construct. Menus or requesting a number - it covers all of those.

As for what went wrong: Actually it adds all numbers to the collection (that debug code should confirm it). You just *remove* the smalest number from the collection between Sorting and Display:

```
bekertek.Sort();
bekertek.Remove(bekertek.Last());  //Should not have done this.
atlag = bekertek.Average();
```

There is a saying: "The 2 most common issues in Progamming is naming variables, chache invalidation and off-by-one errors." But this specific to make is somewhat unique :)

Edit: As Biesi Grr pointed out, you also ignore the first input:

```
int bekert = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //this is never processed
double atlag;
while (bekert > 0 && bekert < 100)
{
    bekert = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    count++;
    bekertek.Add(bekert);
}
```

Maybe you wanted to use a ReadKey() here? There is also no need for a counter - that is actually the job of List.Lenght. In any case, a do..while would make that line unessesary any way.

let us make a fixed, do...while version

```
bool repeat= true;
do{
  int bekert = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if(bekert > 0 && bekert < 100)
    bekertek.Add(bekert);
  else
    repeat = false;
}while(repeat )
```

Comment: It also never adds the first input

Comment: I thought `.Sort` put the numbers in order so `.Last` would be the highest number not the lowest

Comment: @EpicKip I am honestly not sure. In either way, it is not a sensible operation and propably what causes the issue. For the stated purpose it would have to be done prior to sorting.

Comment: I made a small tast https://dotnetfiddle.net/CCzJEA and its like I said. so `.Last` will **not** remove the smallest number.

Comment: @Christopher Other than that I agree. If op just flips the .Add and assignment from .ReadLine he would not need to remove afterward.

Comment: "int bekert = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //this is never processed" 
Yes, i noticed that after I asked this question and that was the solution. But thanks anyway.